# Is there a simple way to review changes before writing file in Neovim on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, vi, neovim

I want to review changes I made to my file before I save it. Is it possible to do this, preferably without using vimrc or installing additional software? I'm using Neovim on Windows.

I tried one of the answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim

Which was:

`:w !diff % -`

This is what I get:

```
'diff' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

shell returned 1
```

I also tried putting the command through bash using Windows Subsystem for Linux:

`:w !bash -c 'diff % -'`

The result:

```
diff: -: Illegal seek

shell returned 2
```

I tried both Windows Command Line and Windows PowerShell and both of the above give the same results. I see there are other answers that include editing vimrc or installing other software, but I wanted to see if there was a simple way to do it first.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out the reason for the error, but I did find a simple workaround:

`:w !bash -c "cat - | diff % -"`

Looks like diff is trying to do a seek that isn't supported by the stream. So buffering it through cat seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).